# First and second derivative of $Y^{\frac{1}{2}}=a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: calculus

Hello I have the regression model $Y^{\frac{1}{2}}=a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which works very well however I am trying to interpret it in terms of change for each different $X_i$ term. For this I need the first and second deriviate for each $X_i
  I have tried using the chain rule to find the first derivative but as I am not that fluent in calculus and ther a multiple X tems I am unsure of my results and hence have not tried to find the second derivate

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If I properly understood, your model is $$\sqrt Y=a+b_1 \times\log(X_1)+b_2\times\sqrt {X_2}$$ and you need the derivatives of $Y$ with respect to $X_1$ and $X_2$. So, let us simply write $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{Y}}\frac{dY}{dX_1}=\frac{b_1}{X_1}$$  $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{Y}}\frac{dY}{dX_2}=\frac{b_2}{2\sqrt{X_2}}$$ So, now, you have the first derivatives that is to say $$\frac{dY}{dX_1}=2\frac{b_1}{X_1}\sqrt Y$$ $$\frac{dY}{dX_2}=\frac{b_2}{\sqrt{X_2}}\sqrt Y$$

Now, just use chain rule to compute $\frac{d^2Y}{dX_1^2}$, $\frac{d^2Y}{dX_2^2}$ and, if required, $\frac{d^2Y}{dX_1 dX_2}$. Trust me, it is very simple since you have all the pieces in your hands (second derivatives will just express as functions of $X_1,X_2,Y$,$\frac{dY}{dX_1}$,$\frac{dY}{dX_2}$.

**Warning**

If I properly understood, your model is $$Y=\Big(a+b_1 \times\log(X_1)+b_2\times\sqrt {X_2}\Big)^2$$ which is nonlinear with respect to its parameters. You then made it linear and fitted $\sqrt Y$ which is linear. Multilinear regression gave you the values of parameters $a,b_1,b_2$ which minimize  the sum of squared errors for $\sqrt Y$ while you measure $Y$. So the values you obtained are just starting guesses for the nonlinear regression.